# Replace String with Value of Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, replace, key-value

I will simplify as much as possible. I have a DataFrame with a list of businesses by state. Some States are abbreviated, some are not. I want to replace the full state name with the Abbreviation (ex: New Jersey to NJ).

I found a cool module "US" found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/us) that lists all the states and their abbreviations in a dictionary. What I would like to do is replace the full name with the abbreviations.

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import us
dfp = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [np.NaN,np.NaN,3,4,5,5,3,1,5,np.NaN], 
                    'B' : [1,0,3,5,0,0,np.NaN,9,0,0], 
                    'C' : ['Pharmacy of Oklahoma','NY Pharma','NJ Pharmacy','Idaho Rx','CA Herbals','Florida Pharma','AK RX','Ohio Drugs','PA Rx','USA Pharma'], 
                    'D' : [123456,123456,1234567,12345678,12345,12345,12345678,123456789,1234567,np.NaN],
                    'E' : ['Assign','Unassign','Assign','Ugly','Appreciate','Undo','Assign','Unicycle','Assign','Unicorn',]})
print(dfp)

statez = us.states.mapping('abbr', 'name')
lst_of_abbrv = statez.keys()
lst_of_states = statez.values()

phrase = "Pharmacy of Oklahoma"

for x in phrase.split():
    if x in lst_of_states:
        x= x.replace(x, 'State')
        print(phrase.split())
```

Right now the only thing I'm able to do is use a string and replace it with the word "State". How do i replace the name with the abbreviations from the dictionary? I've tried and want something like `x= x.replace(x, lst_of_abbrv)`
but it errors because you obviously can't replace with dict_keys.

Extra points if you are able to explain how to apply this to column "C" of the Dataframe

Comment: `x = x.replace(x, statez[x])`?

Comment: don't separate the keys and values into a different lists. Just check `if x in statez`.

Comment: @BallpointBen that was my first go-to but i get a KeyError.  `KeyError: 'Oklahoma'` in my specific example above

Comment: Replace `if x in lst_of_states:` with `if x in lst_of_abbrv:`

Comment: Also, you won't see the change reflected in `phrase`... you can Google why. But to fix it, do `L = phrase.split()`, `for (i,x) in enumerate(L):` and then `L[i] = x.replace(x, statez[x])`. Then, print `L` instead of `phrase.split()`

Comment: @BallpointBen I appreciate the help. Still getting the same `KeyError`, unfortunately. Could you post an Answer so i could see your progression. I feel like I'm missing something super simple here.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted abbr -> full name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I would define a function that would replace the full name of states in a string if any exist or return the original string.

```
def replace_states(company):
    # find all states that exist in the string
    state_found = filter(lambda state: state in company, statez.keys())

    # replace each state with its abbreviation
    for state in state_found:
        company = company.replace(state, statez[state])
    # return the modified string (or original if no states were found)
    return company
```

then you can apply this function to the entire column of the dataframe

```
dfp['C'] = dfp['C'].map(replace_states)
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. I'll be looking more into the steps you used to come to this solution (mainly `.map` and using `lambda`. If I could trouble you, do you have any documentation or links that I could learn up on?

Comment: @MattR pandas map in a dataframe column / series http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#applying-elementwise-python-functions. SO question related to lambda usage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful

Comment: Thanks for those links! I think i understand `.map()`. But your lambda function still has me beat... I don't see how it is working; particularly `lambda state: state in company`. It's not your job to spoon feed me, but if you have the time I would *greatly* appreciate any help

Comment: The lambda defines an unnamed function that takes one argument `state` and returns the boolean value for the statement `state in company`. This could be written equivalently as a function like `def f(state): return state in company`

Comment: Thank you! Now the last step I'm struggling with is to reverse engineer your example to take the full state name and bring back the abbreviation. (ex: New York -> NY). I keep getting KeyErrors. could you guide me in the right direcation? Currently to solve this I just reverse the keys and values in the `statez` dictionary and replace `state.keys()` with `statez.values()` and replace `statez[state]` with the `reversed_dict[state]`

Comment: `statez = us.states.mapping('name', 'abbr')` and you should be set

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete solution:

```
# Note the difference here
statez = us.states.mapping('name', 'abbr')
lst_of_states = statez.keys()
lst_of_abbrv = statez.values()

def sentence_with_states_abbreviated(phrase):
    words = phrase.split()
    for (i,word) in enumerate(words):
        if word in lst_of_states:
            words[i] = statez[word]
    return ' '.join(words)

dfp['C'] = dfp['C'].apply(sentence_with_states_abbreviated)
```

Comment: @MattR: to complete the solution, you'll need to rejoin the words into the phrase with ' '.join(words), and then put that into column **C**.

Comment: I appreciate the help! I wish I could give two answered checks.